# prove that $s=\left \{ x:\left | x \right |\geqslant 1\left. \right \} \right.\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ not open

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

prove that $s=\left \{ x:\left | x \right |\geqslant 1\left.  \right \} \right.\subseteq \mathbb{R}$

I thought that we take a point at the one of the boundray lines $x=1$ or $x=2$ and show that this point is not interior.

i don't know how to do so

I'm a high school student so please don't mock me

Comment: $S^c=\{x:|x|<1\}$ is open. Then $S$ is closed and in $\mathbb{R}$ the only open an closed sets are $\mathbb{R}$ and the empty set.

Comment: Sure, you could do that. Or you could look at its complement.

Comment: @rlartiga nice short solution

Comment: @M.B. i want to write the solution "we take a point at the one of the boundary lines x=1 or x=2 and show that this point is not interior" in a mathematical rigorous proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take $x=1$ this point is in $s$. A ball centered in $1$ with radius $r$ have the form:
$$B(1,r)=(1-r,1+r)$$
For any radius $r$ the points in the interval with $x<1$ are not in $s$ then $x=1$ is not an interior point of $s$ and then $s$ is not open. (Or for any $r$ the points in $(1-r,1) \subset (1-r,1+r)$ are not in $s$)

Comment: you're welcome.